# Immediately invoked expression in browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I use browserify in combination with node.js so that I can use require() in my js files.

I have this piece of code in my game.js:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'snakeGame');

var menuState = require('./menuState.js');
var gameState = require('./gameState.js');

game.state.add('menuState', menuState);
game.state.add('gameState', gameState);
game.state.start('menuState');
```

If i do a `browserify game.js -o bundle.js`, this piece of code is wrapped inside of an immediately invoked expression and all the required js files are more or less concatenated to this bundle.js

How can I achieve to use the game variable in all my required js files? Since the bundle.js the var `game` is in the IIFE scope, I cannot access it. How can I put it outside this scope?

EDIT: i think mike c's solution would have worked too. But i was a bit stupid so i just had to define game globally without var infront, that did the trick...

Comment: For what it's worth, assigning the variable without a `var` in front [actually does attach it to the window object](http://jsfiddle.net/890h84os/). Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

By attaching it to the `window` object.

```
window.game = game;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access your game object elsewhere, export it:

```
module.exports = game;
```

If that gives you cyclic dependencies, you have something to improve in the architecture of your application (In case your architecture is fine and you have cyclic dependencies, you can still ask questions)

From that point:

- If you want to access the game object from other files also bundled in *bundle.js*,

  Simply do `var game = require('game');`
- If you want to access in other scripts loaded in the same page

  - With require:

    Build with `browserify -r ./game.js -o bundle.js`

    Access in other scripts with `var game = require('./game.js');`

    [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/1max08bs/)
  - With require, give an alias to the module:

    Build with `browserify -r ./game.js:game -o bundle.js`

    Access in other scripts with `var game = require('game');`

    [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yv1xso8L/)
  - Without require:

    Build with `browserify -s game ./game.js -o bundle.js`

    Access in other scripts with `window.game`

    [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2fLpu2a2/)

Comment: This is incredibly wrong. `module.exports` will expose it as a module but OP is implying they want it exposed after the bundling process i.e. doesn't want to access it as a module. Since OP is using Browserify, I assume they know how to expose modules. Also, trying to access it with `require('game')` will search for a module called `game` in `node_modules` if they're using a Node.js based setup instead of accessing their local file (instead use `require('./game.js')`).

Comment: @MikeC My explanations may not be clear enough, but I tried it before posting, it works. And my second point is dedicated to expose the game object _after the bundling process_. `require('game')` may look for a module in node_modules if we're using a Node.js based setup, but we're using a browser after the bundling process, aren't we? (I added an example without alias for clarification.)  Also, it is not always obvious that you can do `module.exports = ` with an instantiated object. What would be the benefits of not doing so anyway?

Comment: We are using a browser *after* the bundling process but there's a good chance that the bundling is done in a Node-like environment. In my experience, if you're using Browserify, it's because you like the Node.js way of doing things and you want to keep writing that way even when developing for a browser but perhaps that's just my bias showing. There's nothing wrong with showing that `game` can be applied to `module.exports`, I just feel like OP wasn't asking that considering their use of `require('./gameState.js')` but I guess we both were making assumptions :)